# How to license a mashup?

Tags: license-compatibility, derivative-works, mit, license-file

I have designed a mashup that uses open source software. A substantial part of another open source project was used and the software of that project was made available under the MIT license. There is a clause in the MIT license that states:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

If I would like to use a different license, where do I include the MIT license? Should I open a folder in which to keep all the licenses of the various open source software I used in my mashup? And how do I indicate which license is the main license (the license for my mashup)?

Comment: Thanks @Martijn, the link was useful. What I decided to do was create a NOTICE file that lists each license under a header containing the name of each open source project and then put the main license in a LICENSE file.

Comment: The main reason why I hesitated to vote as close is because the second answer (the one that's not accepted) is much better than the accepted answer. Sounds like a fine solution.